# FirebaseJobDispatcher not scheduling service when app is closed in Nougat

Tags: android, android-service, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler

I've one task to send all the entries to server from SQLite database once internet is connected, whether the application is in foreground or background or closed. And all the entries must go sequentially to server. I'm using firebase job dispatcher for this as below:

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                // the JobService that will be called
                .setService(OfflineJobService.class)
                // uniquely identifies the job
                .setTag("offline-job")
                // one-off job
                .setRecurring(false) //to call job after specific interval and check whether job is pending
                // don't persist past a device reboot
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                // start between 0 and 10 seconds from now
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 10))
                // overwrite an existing job with the same tag
                .setReplaceCurrent(false) //new job should not be created by replacing current job, instead it must continue with already running job
                // retry with exponential backoff
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL) //without this the schedular will not execute when app is closed from background
                // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
                .setConstraints(
                        // only run on an unmetered network
//                        Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK
                        Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
                )
                .build();
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Whenever internet is connected this job is called, executes once and then calls onDestroy I've rescheduled this job when it calls onDestroy() as below:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy called");
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
        dispatcher.cancel("offline-job");
        if(!isOrderCompleted) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Restarting service");
            Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                    // the JobService that will be called
                    .setService(OfflineJobService.class)
                    // uniquely identifies the job
                    .setTag("offline-job")
                    // one-off job
                    .setRecurring(false) //to call job after specific interval and check whether job is pending
                    // don't persist past a device reboot
                    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                    // start between 0 and 30 seconds from now
                    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 30))
                    // overwrite an existing job with the same tag
                    .setReplaceCurrent(false) //new job should not be created by replacing current job, instead it must continue with already running job
                    // retry with exponential backoff
                    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL) //without this the schedular will not execute when app is closed from background
                    // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
                    .setConstraints(
                            // only run on an unmetered network
//                        Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK
                            Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
                    )
                    .build();

            dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
        }

    }
```

This works perfectly fine when app is in foreground or background. But do not work when app is closed.
NOTE: It works when app is closed till Marshmallow. But fails in nougat and above.

Comment: which google play service  version you have?

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

Comment: even tried with compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0', but still same thing is happening

Comment: see this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html